# How to display maps using HERE api with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, api, maps, here-api

I am fairly new to Qt and want to create a program which will display a map of a specific location, (and later i plan on adding things like adjusting zoom, etc). from what I've read on the Qt documentation i can use the HERE api to get the maps. I don't really know though how i can implement this and the example given in the documentation (below) isn't much help :

```
 QMap<QString,QVariant> params;
params["here.app_id"] = "myapp";
params["here.token"] = "abcdefg12345";

QGeoServiceProvider *gsp = new QGeoServiceProvider("here", params);
```

The documentation on the HERE api website is just for javascript, so I don't know where else i can really see more examples for C++.

Could someone please either provide some code which i could then use and work with or guide me on what i should do to achieve what i want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QGeoServiceProvider expects a plugin for the service that you want to use. If you have a plugin for "Here" then you just use the Qt class methods to access the provider.

I expect that you don't have a plugin, though. In that case you should just consider using the REST api for the "Here" service. To use that  you want to look at their REST api instructions and QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkRequest examples.